# java phantomjs change screen resolution

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I need to override screen object.
I used exapmples from here [How do I override window.screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25045727/how-do-i-override-window-screen) and here http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-initialized.html
But my code does not work.

```
PhantomJSDriver phantom = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
phantom.executePhantomJS("onInitialized = function() {\n" +
                "    evaluate(function() {\n" +
                "        window.screen.availWidth = 1024;\n" +
                "        window.screen.availHeight = 768;\n" +
                "    });\n" +
                "};");
System.out.println(phantom.executeScript("return window.screen;"));
phantom.get("http://www.browserleaks.com/javascript");
System.out.println(phantom.executeScript("return window.screen;"));
```

Here is my console output:

```
{availWidth=1440, pixelDepth=32, availTop=0, width=1440, colorDepth=32, availLeft=0, availHeight=860, height=900}
{availWidth=1440, pixelDepth=32, availTop=0, width=1440, colorDepth=32, availLeft=0, availHeight=860, height=900}
```

Note that this line:

```
webDriver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(980, 1461));
```

changes only `availWidth` and `availHeight` properties in screen object.

Can anyone suggest me how to override all properties in screen object?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40311430/set-screen-resolution-in-capserjs-slimerjs/40315588#40315588) you can find an answer.

Comment: it does not work for me